# How to concat variables with component as single variable and pass into another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these small code

```
const myvar = `Some text, ${(
  <Link href={'#'}>this is link</Link>
)}`;
```

I pass this to a component. When it renders, it shows:

```
Some text, [object, object]
```

What is the correct way to concat variables with component and pass into another component?

Comment: this is not a text...

Comment: If you want to concat the <Link> with a string you have to render it to a string first, try `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your attempted solution is rendering as `Some text, [object, object]` is because when you are embedding an object in a template string. If the expression is an object, using the template literal is similar to rendering an object's `toString()` method, which would return `[object, object]` as you experienced. You're inserting a React element into the template literal, which is an object.

To pass it, you can try removing the quotes and just passing it as a single React element prop, as suggested in other answers on this site, which would look something like:

```
<ComponentYouArePassingTo linkComponent={
    <React.Fragment>
        Some text,
        <Link href={'#'}>this is link</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `myvar` JSX as follows and it should render correctly in the component you  pass it to:

```
const myvar = (
  <React.Fragment>
    Some text,{" "}
    <Link href={'#'}>this is link</Link>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: The question was how to pass it to another component.